How to infer parameter types from a type alias that compounds several parameters (uom crate)
I have this crate which defines a base type Quantity<D,U,V> and several type aliases for it. For example, type Length = Quantity<Dim::L, Meter, f64>. How can I define a generic function or a struct that wraps a Quantity but only takes one of those aliases as a type parameter instead of having to reimplement three type parameters.
What I want to successfully implement is the following :
struct ParsedQuantity<Q> {
    quantity: Q,
    additional_field: Something
}

fn parse_value<Q>() -> Result<ParsedQuantity<Q>, &str>;

where Q represents one of those type aliases, so that I can do :

struct Model {
    mass: ParsedQuantity<Mass>
}
let mass = parse_value::<Mass>("1 kg");

If I return directly the quantity, it works to some extent even if my function's signature is parse_value<D, U, V> thanks to rust type inference.
pub fn parse_value<D, U, V>(s: &str) -> Result<Quantity<D, U, V>, &str>
where
    D: Dimension + ?Sized,
    U: uom::si::Units<V> + ?Sized,
    V: uom::Conversion<V> + uom::num_traits::Num,
    Quantity<D, U, V>: FromStr,
{ ... }

let parsed: Length = parse_value("1 m").unwrap();


Here D, U, V are properly inferred.
But when trying to make a version which returns a struct, types can't be inferred anymore in a convenient way. I would have to manually specify each of the three type parameters, which isn't what I want.
What type wizardry can I do so that I can take an alias Q = Quantity<D,U,V> as a single type parameter in my function or struct instead of 3 parameters D, U, V?

I'm not sure I understand the question - you have to have some way for the compiler to deduce the generic type parameters. Either as you have let mass = parse_value::<Mass>("1 kg"); or let mass: ParsedQuantity<Mass> = parse_value("1 kg");

Oh of course, sorry I wasn't clear. My question is how to define that parse_value function, so that the signature can be parse_value instead of parse_value<D, U, V>

I see, I'm guessing you could probably just constrain that Q: FromStr in your parse_value. You can't constrain that Q must be Quantity without also supplying the three generic parameters for it. If Quantity implements some trait that is important to you, you may be able to constrain on that instead.

Thanks! You led me on the right path and it works great, so yeah now my quantity module has no actual mention of Quantity<D,U,V>

Thanks to kmdreko in the comments. It turns out that it isn't something you can do in Rust, however it was enough to constraint a single parameter type to the traits I needed. Now my quantity module has no actual mention of Quantity<D,U,V> while still operating on them.
Here's what it looks like :
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ParsedValue<L>
where
    L: FromStr + Debug + DefaultUnit,
{
    pub raw: String,
    pub parsed: L,
}

impl<L> ParsedValue<L>
where
    L: FromStr + Debug + DefaultUnit,
    <L as FromStr>::Err: Debug,
{
    // Constructor to create a new ParsedValue
    pub fn new(raw: &str) -> Result<Self, ParseError<L>> {
        if let Some(captures) = HAS_UNIT_RE.captures(raw) {
            let _is_reference = captures.get(1).is_some();
            let raw = format!(
                "{} {}",
                captures[2].to_string(),
                if let Some(unit) = captures.get(3) {
                    unit.as_str()
                } else {
                    L::DEFAULT_UNIT
                }
            );
            // Parse the string into L, or handle failure
            let parsed = raw
                .parse::<L>()
                .map_err(|e| ParseError::UnrecognizedQuantity(e))?;
            Ok(ParsedValue {
                raw: raw.to_string(),
                parsed,
            })
        } else {
            Err(ParseError::InvalidQuantityFormat(raw.to_string()))
        }
    }
}

use uom::si::f64 as si;

pub trait DefaultUnit {
    const DEFAULT_UNIT: &str;
}

/// Length (default: kilometers, since distances in geoscience are often measured in km)
pub type Length = ParsedValue<si::Length>;

impl DefaultUnit for si::Length {
    const DEFAULT_UNIT: &str = "km";
}


#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum ParseError<T> where T: FromStr, <T as FromStr>::Err: Debug {
    InvalidQuantityFormat(String),
    UnrecognizedQuantity(<T as FromStr>::Err)
}

use ParseError::*;

impl<T> Display for ParseError<T> where T: FromStr, <T as FromStr>::Err: Debug  {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f,
            "{}",
            match self {
                InvalidQuantityFormat(s) => format!("Invalid Quantity Format : {}", s),
                UnrecognizedQuantity(s) => format!("Unrecognized quantity : '{s:?}'. Check the unit and value.")
            }
        )
    }
}

impl<T> std::error::Error for ParseError<T> where  T: FromStr+Debug, <T as FromStr>::Err: Debug {
}



